# how to proxy remote web frontend(js) using nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

For the web front-end request to `/proxy_route/index.html`, the first request is very simple, we easily get the html file.
Then the browser helps us load js and css. The nightmare comes. The address `/index.js` requested by the browser is not in the rules matched by nginx. How to solve this?
I hope the js address loaded by the browser is also in the form like `/proxy_route/index.js`.
thanks for answer in advance!

Comment: How is it defined in `index.html`? You have a number of options, including: define it correctly in `index.html`, or make it path-relative, or define a `base` HTML element.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for advise. index.html comes from a third-party web server. In my case, it's `tensorboard` in tensorflow.